# Issue with Azure Bot Deployment

Tags: botframework, azure-cli, azure-bot-service

I'm testing to check if I can deploy a dummy bot to Azure Bot Services and run it across multiple channels. I'm using Azure CLI to deploy the bot on ubuntu. The command I ran was, (found on Bot SDK official documentaion)

```
az deployment sub create --template-file "/home/abrar/Work/Bot_POC/testbot-1/deploymentTemplates/template-with-new-rg.json" --location centralindia --parameters appType="UserAssignedMSI" appId="blablabla" tenantId="blablabla2" existingUserAssignedMSIName="TitanBotName" existingUserAssignedMSIResourceGroupName="TitanBot" botId="/subscriptions/2d178cfc-3973-4e06-9ffe-15463849a46c/resourcegroups/TitanBot/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/TitanBotName" botSku=S1 newAppServicePlanName="titanbot" newWebAppName="TitanAssistBot" groupName="TitanBot" groupLocation="centralindia" newAppServicePlanLocation="centralindia" --name "TitanAssist"
```

I've changed the appId and tenantId just in case for this post. The error I'm receiving is,

```
{'code': 'InvalidTemplate', 'target': '/subscriptions/2d178cfc-3973-4e06-9ffe-15463849a46c/resourceGroups/TitanBot/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/storageDeployment', 'message': "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '/subscriptions/2d178cfc-3973-4e06-9ffe-15463849a46c/resourcegroups/TitanBot/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/TitanBotName' for type 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices' at line '1' and column '2061' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.", 'additionalInfo': [{'type': 'TemplateViolation', 'info': {'lineNumber': 1, 'linePosition': 2061, 'path': 'properties.template.resources[2].type'}}]}
```

From the error I'm assuming the **template-with-new-rg.json** has some issues. I got the file from creating an empty bot from Yeoman bot-builder-generator. Upon checking the file I noticed that it had a couple of errors. Link to the file https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot/deploymentTemplates/template-with-new-rg.json

I'm not sure what to do from here, I've tried fixing the json file as suggested by VSCode terminal and upon fixing those, I'm getting another type of error.

```
{'code': 'InvalidTemplate', 'message': "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'storageDeployment' at line '152' and column '9' is invalid. 'ResourceGroup' property is not supported for nested deployments with api-version older than '2017-05-10'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.", 'additionalInfo': [{'type': 'TemplateViolation', 'info': {'lineNumber': 152, 'linePosition': 9, 'path': 'properties.template.resources[1]'}}]}
```

Any suggestions on what I can do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of things wrong here that I can see immediately.

Firstly, `botid` is the **name** of the bot, not an ID number or subscription number. Enter a unique bot name here, such as "TitanTestBot1". This name must be unique across Azure, as Azure Bot resources cannot be created in a specific region and are always global.

Additionally, your service plan name is also `titanbot`. Try giving it a better name.

Finally, you're telling Azure the resource group that your managed identity (which must already exist before creating a bot resource) exists in is called `TitanBot`, but you're also saying you want to create a new resource group for the bot resources called `TitanBot`. These two things cannot both be true. If you want the bot resources to go into `TitanBot`, you need to use the `preexisting-rg` template, not the `new-rg` template. If you want a new resource group, it must have a new name.

At this point, you should carefully review all of the fields in the [Publish your bot to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=multitenant%2Cnewgroup%2Ccsharp) docs and make sure you're giving each field a unique and correct entry.